# XML parsing in Opa

Tags: xml-parsing, opa

Anyone well versed in `xml_parser`s in Opa? I need two idioms:

- *I don't care about an attribute* (it may or may not be present on a tag; if it's present, I don't care about the content) and
- *I don't care about a tag* (it may be there or it may not).

Anyone knows how to express that? As an example say I want to parse:

```
<x a="123">
   <z>...</z>
</x>
```

I want the parser to store value of attribute `a` and content of tag `<v>` and it should work even if `<x>` has optional attribute `b` (or more) and if there is a `<y>` tag before `<z>`.